# Looping to a script

Tags: powershell

I have a problem using loops to add somthing to an object.

This part works:

```
# Get Backup Jobs
$jobs = Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.JobType -eq "Backup"}
foreach ($job in $jobs) {
$jobOptions = New-Object PSObject
$jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "JobName" -value $job.name
$jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enabled" -value $job.isscheduleenabled
```

Output:

```
Jobname,Enabled,...    
Job1,True,...
```

What I want is:

```
VMName,Jobname,Enabled

VM1,Job1,True,...

VM2,Job1,True,...

VM3,Job2,True,...
```

I tried:

```
# Get Backup Jobs
$jobs = Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.JobType -eq "Backup"}
foreach ($job in $jobs) {

$vmnames = ($job.GetObjectsInJob()).name
$jobOptions = New-Object PSObject
$jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VMName" -value 
$vmnames

$jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "JobName" -value 
$job.name
$jobOptions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enabled" -value   
$job.isscheduleenabled
```

This creates:

```
VMName,Jobname,Enabled

VM1 VM2,Job1,True,...
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner loop, I would try looping through the objects instead of looping through the names.  Something along these lines:

```
# Get Backup Jobs
$jobs = Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.JobType -eq "Backup"}

foreach ($job in $jobs) {
    # change starts here; additional loop over VMs
    foreach ($vm in $job.GetObjectsInJob()){

        [array]$jobOptions += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "VMName"  = $vm.name
            "JobName" = $job.name
            "Enabled" = $job.isscheduleenabled
        }

    }
}
```

I borrowed most of the code from gms0ulman's response.

Answer (score 2):

You could use *calculated properties*:

```
$jobs = Get-VBRJob | 
    Where-Object JobType -eq "Backup" |
    Select-Object @{l="VMName"; e={($_.GetObjectsInJob()).name}}, 
    @{l="JobName"; e={$_.name}}, 
    @{l="Enabled"; e={$_.isscheduleenabled}}
```

**Note:** I assume that `$job.GetObjectsInJob().name` returns the VMName.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop over the VMs like so, and use `+=` to add to `$jobOptions`:

```
# Get Backup Jobs
$jobs = Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.JobType -eq "Backup"}

foreach ($job in $jobs) {

    $vmnames = ($job.GetObjectsInJob()).name

    # change starts here; additional loop over VMs
    foreach ($vm in $vmnames){

        [array]$jobOptions += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "VMName"  = $vm
            "JobName" = $job.name
            "Enabled" = $job.isscheduleenabled
        }

    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I have not used jobs in PowerShell, but don't see how this would affect the loop logic.

Answer (score 0):

Martins answer produce this output.

```
    VMName                                        JobName               Enabled
    ------                                        -------               -------
S01                                           Backup Job Server1       True
S02                                           Backup Job Server2       True
{C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6}                     Backup Job Clients       True
```

gms0ulman answer produce this output.

```
VMName                                   JobName               Enabled
------                                   -------               -------
S01                                 Backup Job Server1       True
S02                                 Backup Job Server2       True
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6                   Backup Job Clients       True
```

Comment: Do you want the output from each job to be added to the same object?
What is the actual expected result, using the values in this answer? My understanding is that `C1` to `C6` are stored as a single item within `$vmnames`, based on this output.

Comment: Yes i want to add all the output from $jobs to each single item in $vmnames. So that i have list where I can see VM1 is in Job1, VM2 is in Job1 and for every VM is created a new line.

Comment: Hmmm, try explicitly casting `$vmnames` to an array:  
`[array]$vmnames = ($job.GetObjectsInJob()).name`